# How to post to a Twitter community instead of posting in my Twitter profile

Tags: api, selenium, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

How can I do that? [There is no such a possibility with Twitter official APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets) , so is there another way?

[Image of the audience selection drop down when composing a tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi5Yj.png)

[Image of the audiences available in the drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zambY.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, there's no way to do that via the API right now, so you've answered your own question - you can post to a Community via the Twitter app or website.